# change only listview of a specific id or class

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I've a jQuery mobile app with several listviews on several pages.

I want to manipulate a specific listview by css, but not the other listviews on other pages.

**Listview to manipulate with css:**

```
 <div id="asd">
    <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <h3>Test:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a">
            <div id="result" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
                <h3>Test</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
                    <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS to manipulate listview:**

```
#asd .ui-listview {
    font-size: 0em;
}
```

This does not work. If I remove `#asd`, all listviews are changed, but I want to change only the listview `#asd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
#asd {
    font-size: 0em;
}
```

instead of

```
#asd .ui-listview {
    font-size: 0em;
}
```

If you use the second method, it needs the class ui-listview too, which isn't used in your code.

Comment: The code is not complete. There is some code generated with javascript. With your solution, all text have font size 0. But I want to change only the font size of my listview

Comment: You should first understand HTML and CSS, then you know why it isn't working.

Comment: O.K. I've changed the code, now there are some listviews in my code

Comment: No. The heading has font size 0, but the other items (Acura, Audi, BMW) are unchanged =/

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the element with the class .ui-listview in your html... remove the .ui-listview and it should work regardless.